# where is blend for visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, blend, blend-2012

I see a lot of refs to something called 'blend for visual studio' which I understand a W8 version of blend. I have VS2012 Ultimate installed on W8 and I don't see any blend.

I looked into my MSDN Pro subscription and I don't see neither separate Blend for VS2012 download not VS2012 with Blend download..

How do I get it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is one of the install options that you pick when you do the install (or at least it was in 2012 Professional).

You should be able to get it by going

1. Add/Remove Programmes
2. Select VS 2012 and Clicking Change
3. Click Modify in the VS installer
4. Tick the Blend for Visual Studio option

Comment: and if it's not in the optional features list?

Comment: Do you have Windows 8?  I think it's Windows 8 only.

Comment: I figured it out. Our sysadmin configured the installer without Blend, I modified the config and it showed up on the list. +1

Comment: @StanK, You can't imagine how much time I've spent on looking for the download page and there it is - right before my eyes. Although I do feel stupid now, I want to thank you.

Comment: I get this error in one machine with windows 7 : "Blend for visual studio supports only windows store app development on windows 8. to develop windows presentation foundation(WPF) or silverlight applications , please install Blend + SketchFlow Preview for Visual Studio 2012." 

but in another machine it works fine .. any ideas ?

Comment: it won't run on windows 7

Comment: It starts for me on Windows 7 - does it crash later or is that incorrect?  PS What stumped me is that its a separate app - thought it might be a tool menu option or something under VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

Blend is installed as a seperate application in the VS folder.

If it's installed (see Stank's answer for details on how to do that) then double click the Blend icon in the Visual Studio install folder or in the Start menu.

Happy blending