# does visual studio 2012 shipped with expression blend?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 professional installed, but I can not find Blend with it. Is it shipped with visual studio 2012?

Can I get it for free?

Does it shipped with visual studio 2013?

I want to use it to develop UI for WPF/Silverlight applications.

Comment: Think this might be useful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114611/where-is-blend-for-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 0):

"You can download Blend for Visual Studio 2013 with Visual Studio Express for Windows, Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone, and Visual Studio Professional 2013 and higher."

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/

[Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3062)